# Starting and pausing a timer

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a simple timer that activates on button press, counts up to 10 seconds, increments a set and stops.

Right now, if I press the button during counting, the loop gets faster.

I want to implement that if you press the button again (during the count), it will pause the whole process instead. If you click again, it will start again where you stopped it.

```
let startTime = 0;
let endTime = 10;
let sets = 0;
var toggle;

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", async function myFunction(){
do {
    if (startTime != endTime){
        toggle = true;
        startTime += 1;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = startTime;
        await sleep(1000);       
    }
    else{
        defaultTime = 0;
        sets++;    
        document.getElementById("sets").innerHTML = sets;
        toggle = false;
    }
} while (toggle = true)
});
```

Sorry if this is a very basic question!

Comment: Can you please include your HTML?

Comment: What is the `defaultTime` varibe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for those `Promise` and `async` logic, we can simplify this to:

- On button press:

  - [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) if it doesn't yet exists
  - If it does exist; [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to pause

In the `setInterval`, we can define some logic on that to do when `endTime` is reached.

I've also:

- Placed the logic to reset the timer to a `const`, so we can reuse it easily
- Created a `button` and `display` variable so we don't have to call `getElementById` multiple times
- Added some logic to show the current state on the button

Example:

```js
let startTime = 0;
let endTime = 15;
let timer = null;

const button = document.getElementById("button");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

const resetTimer = () => { 
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function myFunction(){
    if (!timer) {
        button.innerHTML = 'Running';
        timer = setInterval(function() { 
            display.innerHTML = ++startTime;
            if (startTime >= endTime) {
              resetTimer();
              button.innerHTML = 'Press to restart!';
              startTime = 0;
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        resetTimer();
        button.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    }
});
```

```html
<button id='button'>Click me!</button>
<div id='display'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned that I want to be able to restart the timer once the limit is reached,  is there any way to implement that into your answer?

Comment: Please see my edit @Hubris! Added some explanation aswell.